# Throwing custom exceptions without messages

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch, except

I haven't uset custom exceptions before, and now it appears that I might need them but I'm not sure I understood correctly how are they supposed to be used.

Say I have a custom exception like this:

```
class not_found_exception extends exception{ }
```

Then I have a bunch of request handler functions (I think they are called controllers in the wild). And each function can throw different types of exceptions. If the URL doesn't match it throws my custom exception, the script will catch that type of exception and skip to next request handler if it's caught. But other types of exception are not supposed to be caught because they mean that the url matches but there's some other error that should be displayed.

The thing is that my custom exception doesn't need an error message because it would not show up anywhere because its supposed to be caught, but other exceptions do. So is it ok to just throw an empty not_found_exception  exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is simply: yes. That would be ok.
For further information about best-practices regarding Exception I'll refer you to this blog. It may be written for .NET but the theories can still be applied to PHP.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2007/01/30/how-to-design-exception-hierarchies/